# User preferences for icon placement

Tags: gui-design

Is there any study about user preferences icon placement? Do users expect it to be on the left/right side of the top bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Reading Gravity and Strong Fallow Areas**

There's a technical reason for putting icons, avatars, and other secondary UI element in the top right of the screen, at least for websites in a left-to-right languages.

See my answer to this question - [What is the best location to place an identity context control (avatar, name, sign out button)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93415/what-is-the-best-location-to-place-an-identity-context-control-avatar-name-si/93417#93417)

The way that we read and scan pages makes certain areas better or worse locations for primary and secondary UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I believe this style of menu prefers the icon on the right, so it doesn't just look like a long empty bar.

If the bar was shorter though I'd probably put it on the left hand side of the text.

Comment: The bar has actions, it would not be a long empty bar.
We are discussing the icon on the right or on the left side of the logo.
I'm concerned about the expectations when it is on the left because I rely on the logo to go to the home page. Would users expect to go to the home page if they click on the icon?

Comment: Will the icon link somewhere? If thats the case I'd definitely position away from the logo. - Also, how many action are we talking about? Will it fill up the entire bar?

Comment: No, it will trigger a pop over with 'log out' and 'user preferences' options.

Comment: Yeah I'd move it over the right then and leave it there. I'd be really annoyed as a user if a popout kept coming up while I was trying to click something else, especially if I ended up getting logged out or redirected to a user preferences page.